# Large file upload to s3 taking too much time using console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Tried uploading a file of size ~220 MB to s3. I tried doing this through the aws console and it took a lot of time. The upload speed was around 500Kbps on average. I know it isn't a bottleneck because of my network because I'm able to upload this same file to google drive console in about 47seconds.

I've tried uploading to the same directory through aws s3 cli and it is much faster ~2 minutes. I was wondering if there is any issue with doing uploads directly on s3 console. I'm also thinking this would be a risk, because I want my  application to be able to upload to s3 using a signed url, but that is taking a similar amount of time to the console upload time.

Google Drive upload: 49 seconds

S3 console upload: REALLY SLOW (>10 minutes before I gave up).

AWS cli (no custom settings): ~ 2 minutes.

Upload through my UI: (similar to s3 console upload time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using [S3 Multipart API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html) for uploading large files to S3.

> The Multipart upload API enables you to upload large objects in parts.
>   You can use this API to upload new large objects or make a copy of an
>   existing object.

The reason why your CLI upload is quicker because it internally uses the multipart  API for big objects automatically.

> The recommended method is to use aws s3 commands (such as aws s3 cp)
>   for multipart uploads and downloads, because these aws s3 commands
>   automatically perform multipart uploading and downloading based on the
>   file size.

Source : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/qfacts.html

Comment: Oh, I suspected this was true but I missed it while reading the docs. Thanks a ton! One question though. How would it be equally fast through postman? I've tried uploading this through postman (to the signed url) and it was equally quick (around 2 minutes). Shouldn't it be as slow as the console upload?

Comment: From postman documentation : "multipart/form-data is the default encoding a web form uses to transfer data. This simulates filling a form on a website, and submitting it. The form-data editor lets you set key-value pairs (using the data editor for your data.) It also lets you specify the content type for each part of a multi-part form request individually. You can attach files to a key as well."
Link : https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests/